# Perl - How to send a binary (image) file to a remote host from "master" host and create directory structure too?

Tags: perl, binary, transfer

I have done a bunch of reading and some testing to no avail.

I found this script here on stackoverflow which guided me in the right direction but, my abilities are inadequate to modify and fully understand for my needs.

```
#! /usr/bin/perl

use warnings;
use strict;

use File::Basename;
use File::Copy;
use File::Spec::Functions qw/ abs2rel catfile /;
use Net::SSH qw/ sshopen3 /;

my $HOST     = "user\@host.com";
my $SRC_BASE = "/tmp/host";
my $SRC_FILE = "$SRC_BASE/a/b/c/file";
my $DST_BASE = "/tmp/dest";
system("md5sum", $SRC_FILE) == 0 or exit 1;

my $dst_file = catfile $DST_BASE, abs2rel $SRC_FILE, $SRC_BASE;
my $dst_dir  = dirname $dst_file;
sshopen3 $HOST, *SEND, *RECV, *ERRORS,
         "mkdir -p $dst_dir && cat >$dst_file && md5sum $dst_file"
  or die "$0: ssh: $!";

binmode SEND;
copy $SRC_FILE, \*SEND or die  "$0: copy failed: $!";
close SEND             or warn "$0: close: $!";  # later reads hang without this

undef $/;
my $errors = <ERRORS>;
warn $errors if $errors =~ /\S/;
close ERRORS or warn "$0: close: $!";

print <RECV>;
close RECV or warn "$0: close: $!";
```

Scenario:

I have image files in a directory on the "main" host eg `/home/user/public_html/images/red/id100/image01.jpg (thru image012.jpg)`

I would like to copy/send them to my remote host creating the red/id100 path if !-d. (the "/images" folder pre exists.)

I need to send a username and password to the remote host as well to get in. It is a typical cpanel shared server environment.

My main server is dedicated, also with cpanel management installed.

I looked into NET::FTP, File::Remote, Net::Telnet and Net::SFTP but, no examples available that were "dumbed" down to my level.

I will eventually need to do this with ascii files too but, I believe once I get it working with the images, I can figure out xfermode switch, I hope.

Thanks for any help and verbose examples. I always learn great things here.

Answer (score 0):

Using SFTP it should be pretty simple:

```
use Net::SFTP::Foreign;
my $sftp = Net::SFTP::Foreign->new($HOST, passwd => $PASSWD);
$sftp->error and die "Unable to connect to remote host: " . $sftp->error;
$sftp->rput($SRC_BASE, $DST_BASE);
```

...or using ssh+rsync...

```
use Net::OpenSSH;
my $ssh = Net::OpenSSH->new($HOST, passwd => $PASSWD);
$ssh->error and die "Unable to connect to remote host: " . $ssh->error;
$ssh->rsync_put({recursive => 1}, $SRC_BASE, $DST_BASE)
  or die "rsync failed: " . $ssh->error;
```

Comment: Thank you.. will that also create the directory if it does not exist?

Comment: @DulcimerDude: it will create any directory below $DST_BASE. To create $DST_BASE or any parent you can use $sftp->mkpath($DST_BASE)